# sending mail this way?

Tags: html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="mailto:sachin@ifline.com" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Is there a problem if mails are sent this way .. i wanna avoid using PHP codes..

Answer (score 2):

[Many problems](http://www.isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html). It is unusable on the web.